# Using rpc to create CLI-client for controlling daemon

Tags: python, command-line-interface, ipc, rpc

I would like to build a cli-client for a daemon process. To build the cli I would like to use a cli library such as click or fire (others also possible). I thought I could use rpc to control the daemon functions but this does not seem to work.

I tried the following approach using click:

```
######## Daemon ########

from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.argument("a")
@click.argument("b")
def add(a,b):
    return a + b

@cli.command()
@click.argument("a")
@click.argument("b")
def subtract(a,b):
    return a - b

with SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 8000), requestHandler=RequestHandler) as server:
    server.register_introspection_functions()
    server.register_function(cli)
```

The client is

```
    ####### Client ########
    import xmlrpc.client
    
    port = 8000
    proxy_address = "http://localhost:" + str(port) + "/"
    
    with xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(proxy_address) as proxy:
        proxy.cli()
```

The error I get here is: `AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute '__name__'` on `server.register_function(cli)` in the daemon.

Assuming I could fix this I would run in to the problem that output of the `cli` function gets printed in the daemon process rather than the client.

I tried to find a cli client which handles this natively but all I could find was https://github.com/F483/apigen which hasn't been updated in 5 years.

Useful links:

- Click library: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/
- Fire library: https://github.com/google/python-fire
- python xmlrpc : https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://600apples.github.io/dafi/. Validation is included there so  you even don't need to use click